# boundingRectWithSize always returns the same CGRect

Tags: ios, objective-c

I am trying to obtain a substring of an `NSString` that could fit into the frame of a `UILabel`. I am using this code to obtain the CGRect -

```
CGSize  sizeConstraint = CGSizeMake(355, 293.09375);

NSMutableParagraphStyle *paraStyle = [[NSParagraphStyle defaultParagraphStyle] mutableCopy];
paraStyle.lineBreakMode = NSLineBreakByWordWrapping;

NSDictionary *attributes = @{ NSFontAttributeName : bodyFont, NSParagraphStyleAttributeName : paraStyle};

NSAttributedString *attributedText = [[NSAttributedString alloc] initWithString:body attributes:attributes];
CGRect boundingRect = [attributedText boundingRectWithSize:sizeConstraint options:(NSStringDrawingUsesLineFragmentOrigin | NSStringDrawingUsesFontLeading) context:nil];
```

The problem I a am facing is that `boundingRectWithSize` return the same CGRrect after a certain amount of characters in the string. Here is the CGRect I get when the string is 677 characters long -

```
(CGRect) boundingRect = (origin = (x = 0, y = 0), size = (width = 352.515625, height = 281.25))
```

And the CGRect I get when the string is 1354 characters long -

```
(CGRect) boundingRect = (origin = (x = 0, y = 0), size = (width = 352.515625, height = 281.25))
```

No idea why

Comment: Yeah well, I do deserve the downvote

Answer (score 0):

Just realised my mistake -

```
CGSize  sizeConstraint = CGSizeMake(355, 293.09375);
```

should be

```
CGSize  sizeConstraint = CGSizeMake(labelWidth, CGFLOAT_MAX);
```

and then I should be working on the logic to trim the string. Stupid!